# Approximation of differentiable functions

Tags: approximation-theory, weierstrass-approximation

Do there exist a sequence $e_n:\ [-1,1]\to [-1,1]$ of functions such that, for every function $f\in C^s([-1,1])$ we have the following approximation property:

$$\inf_{g\in \text{span}(e_1,\dots e_n)}\|f-g\|_\infty \le C(f)n^{-s-\varepsilon}?$$

(where $\varepsilon>0$). My question is motivated by the case where $e_n(x)=x^{n-1}$, which falls under the name of Polynomial of best approximation, in which the bound with $C(f)n^{-s}$ has been [proved](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1007/s00211-021-01173-z#:%7E:text=For%20analytic%20functions%2C%20we%20show%20that%20the%20best,the%20same%20degree%20by%20a%20factor%20of%20n1%2F2.), and I conjecture it is not possble to do strictly better.